# Managed package visualforce page not enabled for lightning experience, yet is displaying in lightning automatically

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, summer-16

When we enter the URL for a packaged Visualforce page, it displays inside the Lightning Experience.  The problem is, the page is not enabled in lightning via 'Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages'.

This is a new behaviour for Summer 16, as it presents in Salesforce 'Classic' for Spring 16 for the same packaged page and package version.

I searched the known issues in salesforce but could find no mentions.

For that page, we do not want the lightning experience as it causes us some integration headache.

Have others observed this behaviour?